# Regarding In app Purchase Or payment gateway

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal, in-app-purchase, stripe-payments

I am developing iOS app which basically allows to purchase coupon codes from our server .
This coupon code is shown in shop and then we can purchase physical goods of that .

I am really confused which payment mechanism i should choose,

**In app purchase** : Allows to sell only digital contents .  We Cant sell physical goods .

**Payment Gateway (like Stripe, PayPal etc)** : Only physical goods can be purchased .

Should i go for In app purchase or payment gateway . Please help me .

Answer (score -1):

Email apple, My gut leans to in app purchase, the 'code' could be considered a digital good, but something like this is just ambiguous enough to require a email trail for when your app gets bounced back

Comment: Thanks , Damian for the reply . Sure i will mail to apple . My concern is if go for Payment Gateway the app should not be rejected by app store .

Comment: Its too ambiguous I think, depending on the reviewer you will get a different response I think, its better to submit with a paper-trail of XX said it was ok, rather than to submit and have it bounce (only to resubmit later and have it bounce from a different reviewer) . because a code is a digital object, but if that code can only be used to purchase something physical then its a physical object